# convert to df column to datetime - raise SettingWithCopyWarning

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime

I have a Pandas DataFrame 'Date' column that I'm trying to convert to datetime. It's converting, and raising  "SettingWithCopyWarning"

I tried to follow other excellent explanations like: [How to deal with SettingWithCopyWarning in Pandas?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20625582/how-to-deal-with-settingwithcopywarning-in-pandas), and others, but couldn't figure it out.
Thank you all!

**my original code:**

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

data = pd.DataFrame(pd.read_excel('Restaurant Shifts Data.xlsx', na_values='-'))    # (-) value in cash
data.fillna(0)

columns = ['Waiter','Start','Finish','Cash','Credit','Total Hours','Total Shift','Date','Shift','Shift manager']
restaurant_data = data[columns]
restaurant_data[['Cash', 'Credit','Total Shift']] = restaurant_data[['Cash', 'Credit','Total Shift']].apply(pd.to_numeric)
restaurant_data['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(restaurant_data['Date'])
restaurant_data['Day'] = restaurant_data['Date'].dt.day_name()
```

**Tried different combinations with .loc:** restaurant_data.loc[:,'Date'] = pd.to_datetime(restaurant_data['Date'])

> Date *(data example)*
>
> 0  2020-01-01
>
> 1      2020-01-01
>
> 2      2020-01-01

**Full error message**

```
...\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py:2963: SettingWithCopyWarning: 
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead

See the caveats in the documentation: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#returning-a-view-versus-a-copy
  self[k1] = value[k2]
<ipython-input-51-0b817be48c52>:10: SettingWithCopyWarning: 
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead

See the caveats in the documentation: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#returning-a-view-versus-a-copy
  restaurant_data['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(restaurant_data['Date'])
```

Comment: `restaurant_data = data[columns].copy()`. Also, `data=data.fillna()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the [`.loc` syntax](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) for getting and setting values. This syntax has the benefit of being clearer (i.e., it is more apparent whether you are referencing rows or columns).

You write that you tried `.loc`, but you don't show the code that didn't work. Try the below.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

data = pd.DataFrame(pd.read_excel('Restaurant Shifts Data.xlsx', na_values='-'))    # (-) value in cash
data.fillna(0)

columns = ['Waiter','Start','Finish','Cash','Credit','Total Hours','Total Shift','Date','Shift','Shift manager']
restaurant_data = data.loc[:, columns]
restaurant_data.loc[:, ['Cash', 'Credit','Total Shift']] = restaurant_data.loc[:, ['Cash', 'Credit','Total Shift']].apply(pd.to_numeric)
restaurant_data.loc[:, 'Date'] = pd.to_datetime(restaurant_data.loc[:, 'Date'])
restaurant_data.loc[:, 'Day'] = restaurant_data.loc[:, 'Date'].dt.day_name()
```

Comment: Thank you for the descriptive answer, it was very helpful!